# Can i update wordpress version of my PHP5 customised wordpress site into latest wordpress version?

Tags: wordpress, version, customization

Can i update wordpress version of  my PHP5 customised wordpress site into latest wordpress version?  Now it is in 4.6 and i want to move it to 4.9.1. Any issues will be rised?

Comment: you can use PHP Compatibility Checker to check if your theme can work with several versions of php
https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-compatibility-checker/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it and mostly that will not cause any of issue. But before do WordPress update make sure you have to take backup for your databases once.
First of all take backup for database and make your full theme folder backup and store it as a zip , so if any issue will be raised then you directly unzip that as a theme and that will work fine.

If you have do your WordPress customization all in function.php file then your new WordPress will work perfect with your changes.

If your site have Woocomerce or other more useful plugin for front site then you should take backup for that also.

After WordPress update you may be find plugin update so do it one by one.